# Number of days in next month not working

Tags: php

I'm using the below code to get the number of days in the next month. It displays 31 when there is 30 days in November.  How do i solve?

```
echo date('t',mktime(0,0,0,date("M",strtotime("+1 month")),1,date("Y")));
```

Comment: can I ask...why all the trouble if you just want the number of days in the next month?? just curious

Comment: I'm making a calendar application.  I need the number of days next month, so i can subtract the days left of the current month.  I need to show the dates 30 days from now in one grid, not separated by months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date("M",strtotime("+1 month"))` returns a string (`Nov`), but mktime expects all arguments to be integers. This means that you're getting a 0 value injected instead of next month, which will effectively give you the number of days in January

```
date("n",strtotime("+1 month"))
```

will return the month number

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php

This is already built into PHP and something like:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date = $date->add( new DateInterval( 'P1M' ) );
echo $date->format( 'm' );
```

will give you 11 for November when in October.

Comment: he asked the numbers of days in november. Not the month number

Comment: If you read the whole post, the function for counting days in a month is already built in. The only difficult part is determining the next month's number (needed for the function) so I supplied that. It should be trivial to solve from what I've given.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$days = cal_days_in_month(strtotime("first day of next month"));
```